# img alternative text instead of broken image icon

Tags: html, image

I am sending a html built email body..
Is there a way to display an alternate text while the images are not yet loaded? 
I tried overlapping two divs with img and text, it is working but the problem is that the broken-image icon is showing.

```
<div style="width:100%;min-height:50px!important;text-align:center;background-color:#eee;border-bottom:solid 2px #aaa">
    <div style="min-height:10px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="min-height:30px">
        <div style='width:200px;margin:0 auto;'>
            <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
                <div style='position:relative;'>
                    <div style='position:absolute; height:30px;width:200px;z-index:1000;'>
                        <img height="30" width="200" alt="View Presentation" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/X/1/Q/v/b/2/green-button.svg">
                    </div>
                    <div style='position:absolute;height:30px;width:200px;background-color:#EEE;'>
                        Click here to view
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="min-height:10px">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Kindly see my work here..

http://jsfiddle.net/msvillanueva/aYuAd/1/

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery plugin can help you

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

> Lazy Load is delays loading of images in long web pages. Images outside of viewport are not loaded until user scrolls to them. This is opposite of image preloading.
>   Using Lazy Load on long web pages will make the page load faster. In some cases it can also help to reduce server load.

Comment: I am generating a html body that will be sent as email. I am not coding a usual html body.